# How to respond with child object based on its parent id?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a parent class and a child class, like so:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Bird(Animal)
    wingSpan = models.DecimalField()
```

Here's the view to get birds:

```
class BirdViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bird.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BirdSerializer
```

And here is the serializer:

```
class BirdSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bird
        fields = ['age', 'wingSpan']
```

In the database, jango appropriately created an animal_prt_id field in the birds table, so that this view/serializer pair knows where to find the age, which is mapped to the parent class, Animal.

How to make a view/serializer pair that does the opposite, meaning, it receives the id of an Animal and responds with the complete Bird (or with any other Animal subclass I might have)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an useful package called [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils) that provides an [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) logic.

TLDR: After setting up the package, your code will sort of look like this

`bird = Animal.objects.filter(pk=animal_id).select_subclasses("bird")`

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out.

Comment: the InheritanceManager works as advertised: all my instances are of type Bird now, so that's progress. However, when I add the field wingSpan to the serializer so that it gets send on the response, Django complains that field isn't on that model (because it uses the Animal model). It works if I change the serializer model to Bird, but then I'm back to my original problem.

Comment: It worked. Other than using the InheritanceManager, I also had to adapt the serializer of the parent class to return the serializer of the child class, based on the object type. Thanks again!

Comment: Good job, I'm glad I could help